# Different results from the same integral with two different methods

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$\int x^2(x-3)^{11}\,dx$$

By substituting (let $t=(x-3)$), it results in one answer and *integration by parts* (let $u=x^2$ and $v=(x-3)^{11}$), results in something that is totally different from the first.

**by substitution method**

let $t=(x-3)$
then $x^2=(t^2+6t+9)$

$\int x^2(x-3)^{11}\,dx=\int (t^2+6t+9)t^{11}\,dt$

$=\frac{t^{14}}{14}+\frac{6t^{13}}{13}+\frac{3t^{12}}4 +C$

$=\frac{(x-3)^{14}}{14}+\frac{6(x-3)^{13}}{13}+\frac{3(x-3)^{12}}4 +C$

**and by *Integration by parts***

$\int x^2(x-3)^{11}\,dx$

$=\frac{x^2(x-3)^{12}}{12}-\int\frac{(x-3)^{12}}{12}(2x)dx$

$=\frac{x^2(x-3)^{12}}{12}-\frac{x(x-3)^{13}}{78}+\frac{(x-3)^{14}}{1092} +C$

these two solutions are different from each other.

Comment: Could you show what you did and what you obtained ?

Comment: Show a bit of work so we can help find your mistake. Those two methods, performed correctly, should yield the same answer.

Comment: Conveniently, this is a polynomial, and therefor extremely straightforward to check. You could multiply it all out. Or you could check your two answers by differentiating them, and seeing if they are the same polynomial as the integrand. Or you could ask W|A if you just want a correct answer to check against.

Comment: Did you substitute $x=t+3$ back afterwards?

Comment: Sir the question is edited.

Answer (score 3):

Those two results are actually the same, as you can see here:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-3%29%5E14%2F14%2B6%28x-3%29%5E13%2F13%2B3%28x-3%29%5E12%2F4

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%28x-3%29%5E12%2F12-x%28x-3%29%5E13%2F78%2B%28x-3%29%5E14%2F1092

in the "Expanded form" entry.

Answer (score 1):

The first:

$\dfrac{(x-3)^{14}}{14}+\dfrac{6(x-3)^{13}}{13}+\dfrac{3(x-3)^{12}}{4}+C=(x-3)^{12}\left[\dfrac{(x-3)^{2}}{14}+\dfrac{6(x-3)}{13}+\dfrac{3}{4}\right]+C=(x-3)^{12}\left[\dfrac{x^2}{14}-\dfrac{6x}{14}+\dfrac{9}{14}+\dfrac{6x}{13}-\dfrac{18}{13}+\dfrac{3}{4}\right]+C=(x-3)^{12}\left[\dfrac{x^2}{14}+\dfrac{3x}{91}+\dfrac{3}{364}\right]+C$

The second:

$\dfrac{x^2(x-3)^{12}}{12}-\dfrac{x(x-3)^{13}}{78}+\dfrac{(x-3)^{14}}{1092} +C=(x-3)^{12}\left[\dfrac{x^2}{12}-\dfrac{x^2}{78}+\dfrac{3x}{78}+\dfrac{x^2}{1092}-\dfrac{6x}{1092}+\dfrac{9}{1092}\right]+C=(x-3)^{12}\left[\dfrac{x^2}{14}+\dfrac{3x}{91}+\dfrac{3}{364}\right]+C$